# Require tags for bbPress topics

Tags: tags, bbpress

I want to require my forum members to enter **at least one word into the "tags"-line**, when they are creating a new topic.

As regards plugins and solutions, what I found so far is the [**WyPiekacz-plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wypiekacz/) which works well for posts: You can define rules for the data entered. It did not work for the creation of forum posts.

What I also found is the answer to "**[require one tag for each post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/31809/)**" here in WordPress Answers which contains the code for a small plugin.

While exploring the php-files of bbPress, I added the last two lines to the following snippet within **`bb_post.php`**:

```
$topic = trim( $_POST['topic'] );
$tags  = trim( $_POST['tags']  );

if ('' == $topic)
    bb_die(__('Please enter a topic title'));

if ('' == $tags)
    bb_die(__('Please enter tags'));
```

In my understanding, that should do the trick - but still it doesn't. Or am I using the wrong file? My installation uses bbPress within BuddyPress.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Found any helpful research?

Comment: I added to the question what I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

In the back end, it's a matter of using the hook [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post), as **`topic`** is a Custom Post Type.

If no Tags are filled, saving is cancelled and a link is presented so the user can go back to the editing screen.
*But, there's one caveat:* the title is not preserved, if it is a new topic it comes back blank and if it is an existing topic any changes are lost. The content and topic attributes are preserved.
<sup>I'm not quite sure there is a solution for this...</sup>

[image: missing tags]

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_wpse_82956', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Require Tags for new bbPress Topic
 */
function save_post_wpse_82956( $post_id, $post_object ) 
{
    // Auto save or Ajax
    if ( 
        ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        || ( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) )
        return;

    // Correct post_type
    if ( 'topic' != $post_object->post_type )
        return;

    // First instance of the post (right after clicking "New Topic")
    if( 'auto-draft' == $post_object->post_status )
        return;

    if ( empty( $_POST['tax_input']['topic-tag'] ) ) 
        wp_die( '<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">' . __( '&laquo; &laquo; Please, add tags to the topic' ) . '</a>' );

}
```

---

And in the front end, a couple of bbPress action hooks and a simple check <strike>are enough</strike> (when posting multiple replies, a Javascript workaround is necessary, check comments):

```
add_action( 'bbp_new_topic_pre_extras', 'check_front_end_tags_wpse_82956' );
add_action( 'bbp_new_reply_pre_extras', 'check_front_end_tags_wpse_82956' );

function check_front_end_tags_wpse_82956()
{
    if( empty( $_POST['bbp_topic_tags'] ) )
    {
        // WORKAROUND FOR LINKS WITH HASH TAG, e.g., topic/lorem-ipsum#post-91
        // Necessary when posting multiple replies that generate hashed links
        // OTHERWISE A SIMPLE href="javascript:history.go(-1) WOULD WORK
        ?><script>
        function goBack() {
            if (window.history && history.pushState) {
                history.replaceState("", "", "?no-tags=true);
                history.go(-1);
            }
        }
        </script><?php

        wp_die( '<a href="javascript:goBack()">' . __( '&laquo; &laquo; Please, add tags to the topic' ) . '</a>' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your detailed answer with a lot of explanations! This afternoon, I will try it out in the local installation on my laptop.

Comment: Tried it. It works! Just to mention it for other newbies: The part for the front end goes to functions.php in the active theme.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tested all the code inside a custom plugin, no `functions.php`, check: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615